# advertisement of the Open Data website on CrossValidated "off-topic" messages

Tags: discussion

FYI, I asked this question on the CrossValidated meta website, which may be of interest to the few active users here:

[Off-topic message: why is the "open data" website made so prominent?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6655/off-topic-message-why-is-the-open-data-website-made-so-prominent)